# how to set fullcreen editText in portrait for Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-method

When the screen is in landscape mode, the IME is full-screen default,
but we can set it to not fullscreen. But in portrait mode, is there
any way to invoke full-screen IME?

Comment: I wish. I have wanted this as a native call in so many apps...

Answer (score 0):

No way to do that. It is up to IME implementation.

See this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/Wihil_srtN4

Comment: that's mean if i custom IME by extends input method service, so will it not work?

Comment: Yes it will work if you create your own IME. But I don't think that it can be done to custom IME...